# How can I add the "Accept-Encoding" header to my CloudFront distribution?

Tags: amazon-s3, compression, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I opened the CloudFront Dashboard and clicked on the distribution ID, then clicked on the Origin tab and clicked, selected the default origin and then clicked on Edit. 
Tried to add "Accept-Encoding" in the 'Header Name' under Custom Origin Headers and set its value as "gzip", but it shows the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidArgumentException: The parameter HeaderValue for Accept-Encoding is not empty. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: 05685bb6-ca02-11e7-8a62-0b7037d34a58)
```

What can be done to enable gzip compression through CloudFront?

Comment: If you are trying to enable clients to compress files / data before sending to CloudFront, you cannot. This is not supported. One of the reasons is that it is easy to create zip (gzip) files that when decompressed explode in size (Zip Bomb). A bad actor could bring down your CloudFront / Backend connection very easily with this type of hack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not configure CloudFront to cache based on `Accept-Encoding` header. Quote from [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-selecting):

> You can configure CloudFront to cache based on the value of any request header except the following:
>
> - Accept-Encoding,
> - Connection,
> - ...

However, you can configure CloudFront to compress [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront-file-types)
file types.
In CloudFront console "**Compress objects automatically**" select **Yes**.

Note: Only files that have a size be between 1,000 and 10,000,000 bytes are compressed. When you use S3 or any other custom origin, CloudFront must get the response with a `Content-Length` header so it can determine whether the size of the file is in the range that CloudFront compresses. If you are using S3, go to CORS configurations and add the `Content-Length` header to the list of allowed headers.

If you want **your origin** to compress files, settings depend on the server you have running on that origin. **Server** should be set up to serve gzip-ed content to CloudFront with `Content-Encoding: gzip` header, so it won't be compressed by CloudFront.
These are basic guidelines, but exact setting depends on your concrete configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much.